# jquery - how to detect meaningful edits to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite

My application allows users to create and edit questions for interviews.

Initially, the user is presented with a set of "standard" questions, with each question displayed in its own textarea.

Users are allowed to edit/customize these "starter" questions in these textareas.

If the question is changed (in a meaningful way), the question is saved as a new question.

However, non-meaningful changes should not trigger the addition of the "edited" class.

My challenge is that I want to detect when the textarea has changed, BUT I don't want to count the addition of a space or just clicking into the textarea as an edit that is worthy of updating the database.

My textarea is like this:

```
<textarea id="question_1" class="textarea_enabled">{text filled from database}</textarea>
```

When my jquery/javascript is like this:

```
$(document).on('keypress','.textarea_enabled',function() {
    var charCount = $(this).val().replace(/\s/g,'').length;
    if(newChar > 1) {
        $(this).addClass('edited');
    }
});
```

It doesn't work because length includes measuring the text that is already there from the database.

For example if the question is already 30 characters, then the above code adds the class on the first key stroke because its already greater than 1.

Alternatively, I tried:

```
$(document).on('input blur','.textarea_enabled',function() {
    $(this).addClass('edited);
});
```

but of course, there's no counting or evaluation of how much has changed in this code. As a result, clicking into the input with the mouse and then clicking outside of the textarea is sufficient to trigger adding the "edited" class.

To be precise, I'm not looking for the total number of characters in a textarea (as many of the other SO questions address) nor am I attempting to limit the number of characters in the textarea.

I need a function that detects meaningful edits. Edits within the existing question string (eg., correcting spelling or removing a word) should always trigger the "edited" class addition.  On the other hand "incremental" non-space or other non-visual keypresses, clicking in and out of the field, etc. should NOT trigger the addition of the "edited" class.

As an example, a space entered at the end of the question would be a meaningless space. But, a space entered in the "interior" of the existing question to separate words previously entered incorrectly (eg., "thedog" changed to "the dog") would be a "meaningful" change.

I could just compare the submitted edits to the stored values in the SQLite database, but this seems like an "expensive" route and eliminates the opportunity to visually cue the user when changes are sufficient to be recognized (i.e. the addition of the "edited" class).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have an edit and save button to change the textarea data or just clicking and hovering out saves the data?

Comment: Multiple questions are displayed simultaneously.  The addition of the "edited" class serves to flag those that should be included in the Post data and handled on the server.  The textareas are all editable merely by clicking into the textareas

Comment: Why no just check keypress for the type of key that was pressed. If its not space or meta or ctl etc... then save?

Comment: I don't think that would work.  For example, a space entered at the end of the question would be a meaningless space.  A space entered in the "interior" of the existing question to separate words previously entered incorrectly (eg., "thedog" changed to "the dog") would be a "meaningful" change.

Comment: hey @globalSchmidt, I was just curious if you'd want the user to: (1) assess if what he/she did was 'meaningful'; and (2) let them decide if they want to create a new question out of what they edited? (i.e. a button they can press)

Comment: @Noel - that's a good way to think about it. However, my philosophy going in was to make the question editing as clean and simple as possible. The evaluation of meaningful changes is more of a backend efficiency evaluation vs. a user valuation - i.e. not adding a new question to the database just because one or more spaces were added at the end while still recognizing all other legitimate edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

- count initial string lengths for multiple `<textarea>`s
- `keyup` event checks a `trim`med string against initial lengths (excludes leading/ trailing spaces) and only sets the class where 'meaningful' new characters or spaces entered
- updates string length for relevant `<textarea>` for subsequent checking

```js
// hash for question lengths
var questionCharCount = {};
// sample questions
var questions = [
  'stuff from database',
  'more stuff from database',
  'quick brown fox'
];

// intialise questions - your DB code goes here
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    id = 'question_' + i; 
    $('#' + id).val(questions[i-1].trim());
    questionCharCount[id] = $('#' + id).val().length;
  }
});

// keyup event to decide on meaningful edit based on trimmed lengths
$(document).on('keyup', '.textarea_enabled', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var newCharCount = $(this).val().trim().length;
  if (newCharCount !== questionCharCount[id]) {
    $(this).addClass('edited');
    questionCharCount[id] = newCharCount;
    console.log('meaningful edit occurred in ' + id);
  }
});
```

```css
.edited {
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="question_1" class="textarea_enabled"></textarea>
<textarea id="question_2" class="textarea_enabled"></textarea>
<textarea id="question_3" class="textarea_enabled"></textarea>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and the code snippet does exactly what I need.  I ended rewriting this a bit because (of course) the data is dynamically loaded and the question_ids are not always sequential numbers. I just iterated over all the loaded question ids with `$('.textarea_enabled').foreach(function() {id = $(this).attr('id'); $(this).val().trim(); questionCharCount[id] = $(this).val().length;})`.  The rest worked beautifully!   Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)